# How can I express foldr in terms of foldMap for type-aligned sequences?

Tags: haskell, types, monoids, type-variables, foldable

I'm playing around with [type-aligned sequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-aligned-0.9.6/docs/Data-TASequence.html), and in particular I'm messing around with the idea of folding them. A foldable type-aligned sequence looks something like this:

```
class FoldableTA fm where
  foldMapTA :: Category h =>
                (forall b c . a b c -> h b c) ->
                fm a b d -> h b d
  foldrTA :: (forall b c d . a c d -> h b c -> h b d) ->
             h p q -> fm a q r -> h p r
  foldlTA :: ...
```

It's pretty easy to implement `foldrTA` in terms of `foldMapTA` by first using `foldMapTA` to convert the sequence to a type-aligned list in the naive way (i.e., using the type-aligned list category) and then folding over that list. Unfortunately, this can be quite inefficient because long lists may be prepended to short ones. I've been trying to figure out a way to use a trick similar to the one used in `Data.Foldable` to define the right and left folds more efficiently, but the types are making me dizzy. `Endo` does not seem general enough to do the trick, and every step I take in other directions leads me to more type variables than I can keep track of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that this typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module FoldableTA where

import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))

class FoldableTA fm where
  foldMapTA :: Category h => (forall b c . a b c -> h b c) -> fm a b d -> h b d
  foldrTA :: (forall b c d . a c d -> h b c -> h b d) -> h p q -> fm a q r -> h p r
  foldrTA f z t = appEndoTA (foldMapTA (\x -> TAEndo (f x)) t) z

newtype TAEndo h c d = TAEndo { appEndoTA :: forall b. h b c -> h b d  }

instance Category (TAEndo h) where
    id = TAEndo id
    TAEndo f1 . TAEndo f2 = TAEndo (f1 . f2)
```

No idea if it makes any sense, but with so many type indexes around, I doubt that there is much type-checking code that does *not* make sense.

Comment: Indeed, I'm pretty sure anything that terminates and has the right type is guaranteed by parametricity to be correct. Thanks a lot!