# How should I traverse type-aligned sequences?

Tags: haskell, applicative, gadt

Last summer, I considered the notion of folding a type-aligned sequence, [asking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985070/how-can-i-express-foldr-in-terms-of-foldmap-for-type-aligned-sequences) how one might implement an analogue of `foldr` in terms of an analogue of `foldMap`. Joachim Breitner was able to do it with the help of a tricky newtype. Now I decided to think about the notion of *traversing* a type-aligned sequence. The first thought I had was the simple translation

```
class TATraversable t where
  ttraverse :: Applicative f
            => (forall x y . c x y -> f (d x y))
            -> t c p q -> f (t d p q)
```

which turns out to be basically the same as `mapMThrist` from the `thrist` package. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be strong enough to implement

```
tfoldMap :: Category d
         => (forall x y . c x y -> d x y)
         -> f c p q -> d p q
```

Since the `Monoid` of `Foldable` is replaced by a `Category` for `TAFoldable`, the `Applicative` of `Traversable` has to be replaced by something stronger. I came up with the following, based on Atkey-style indexed applicative functors, but it feels a tad awkward, especially since the indices seem to like to end up backwards. Basically, I just threw types at the wall until some of them stuck. Is there some more principled/understandable approach?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes,
      GADTs, PolyKinds #-}

module ITrav where

--Not using this because it's not polykinded
--import Data.Functor.Indexed
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
```

Polykinded versions of indexed Atkey-style functors. I don't actually need poly-kindedness for any of this code, but I think anyone actually *using* it will expect it to work with phantoms of all kinds. Besides, this gives me a good excuse to copy the definitions here for reference:

```
class IxFunctor f where
  imap :: (a -> b) -> f j k a -> f j k b

class IxFunctor m => IxPointed m where
  ireturn :: a -> m i i a

class IxPointed m => IxApplicative m where
  iap :: m i j (a -> b) -> m j k a -> m i k b
```

A notion of mappability for type-aligned sequences, based on a method in `type-aligned`:

```
class TAMappable t where
  tmap :: (forall x y . c x y -> d x y)
       -> t c p q -> t d p q
```

My notion of foldability for type-aligned sequences:

```
class TAFoldable f where
  tfoldMap :: Category d
           => (forall x y . c x y -> d x y)
           -> f c p q -> d p q
```

My best-so-far notion of traversability for type-aligned sequences:

```
class (TAMappable t, TAFoldable t) => TATraversable t where
  ttraverse :: IxApplicative m
            => (forall x y . c x y -> m x y (d x y))
            -> t c p q -> m p q (t d p q)
```

Machinery to map by traversing:

```
newtype Identity2 x y z = Identity2 {runIdentity2 :: z}

instance IxFunctor Identity2 where
  imap f (Identity2 x) = Identity2 (f x)

instance IxPointed Identity2 where
  ireturn = Identity2

instance IxApplicative Identity2 where
  iap (Identity2 f) (Identity2 x) = Identity2 (f x)

tmapDefault :: TATraversable t => (forall x y . c x y -> d x y) -> t c p q -> t d p q
tmapDefault f = runIdentity2 . ttraverse (Identity2 . f)
```

Machinery to fold by traversing:

```
newtype Consty d x y z = Consty { getConsty :: d x y }
instance IxFunctor (Consty d) where
  imap _ (Consty x) = Consty x
instance Category d => IxPointed (Consty d) where
  ireturn _ = Consty id
instance Category d => IxApplicative (Consty d) where
  iap (Consty x) (Consty y) = Consty (y . x)

tfoldMapDefault :: (Category d, TATraversable t) => (forall x y . c x y -> d x y) -> t c p q -> d p q
tfoldMapDefault f = getConsty . ttraverse (Consty . f)
```

Proof that at least the simplest type-aligned sequence admits a (somewhat weird) `TATraversable` instance.

```
infixr 5 :::
data TAL :: (k -> k -> *) -> k -> k -> * where
  Nil :: TAL c x x
  (:::) :: c y z -> TAL c x y -> TAL c x z

instance TAMappable TAL where
  tmap = tmapDefault

instance TAFoldable TAL where
  tfoldMap = tfoldMapDefault

instance TATraversable TAL where
  ttraverse _ Nil = ireturn Nil
  ttraverse f (x ::: xs) = imap (flip (:::)) (ttraverse f xs) `iap` f x
```

---

I think I've found a hint to the source of backwardsness. My type-aligned list starts with the *end* of the composition chain, which makes it fight with the `IxApplicative` index order. One option is to replace the definition of `TAL` above with

```
data TAL :: (k -> k -> *) -> k -> k -> * where
  Nil :: TAL c x x
  (:::) :: c x y -> TAL c y z -> TAL c x z
```

which makes the obvious instance work:

```
instance TATraversable TAL where
  ttraverse _ Nil = ireturn Nil
  ttraverse f (x ::: xs) = imap (:::) (f x) `iap` ttraverse f xs
```

But this is kind of yucky to look at, to be honest.

Comment: I think I'm *beginning* to understand the backwardsness: my notion of type-aligned sequence starts at the *end* of the composition chain, and moves towards the *beginning*. This (I guess?) makes the index applicatives wonky. But it makes other things prettier to look at. Hmmmm.

Comment: Why is the second `TAL` yucky? That's the definition [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-aligned-0.9.6/docs/Data-TASequence-ConsList.html) and [here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Star.agda) too.

Comment: @András Kovács, it's not inherently bad, but it means that folding up the list you have to replace each `Cons` with `>>>` rather than `.`. I'm not actually sure which style ends up more convenient in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out one way to do it: swap the type indices in the definition of `ttraverse`:

```
class (TAMappable t, TAFoldable t) => TATraversable t where
  ttraverse :: IxApplicative m
            => (forall x y . c x y -> m y x (d x y))
            -> t c p q -> m q p (t d p q)

newtype Consty d y x z = Consty { getConsty :: d x y }
instance Category d => IxApplicative (Consty d) where
  iap (Consty x) (Consty y) = Consty (x . y)
```

Then things work out the way I was originally hoping. I don't know if this is actually a good idea, though.

---

Fortunately, it seems that either way I do it, I can reverse, with an analogue of `Control.Applicative.Backwards.Backwards`!

```
newtype IxBackwards m i j a = IxBackwards {ixForwards :: m j i a}

instance IxFunctor f => IxFunctor (IxBackwards f) where
  imap f (IxBackwards x) = IxBackwards (imap f x)

instance IxPointed f => IxPointed (IxBackwards f) where
  ireturn = IxBackwards . ireturn

instance IxApplicative f => IxApplicative (IxBackwards f) where
  iap (IxBackwards fs) (IxBackwards xs) =
    IxBackwards $ imap (flip ($)) xs `iap` fs
```

The order of the indices in the type signature of `ttraverse` seems to determine the traversal order. Traversing `IxBackwards` will, if I'm not very confused, reverse that order:

```
traverseOpposite :: (IxApplicative m, TATraversable t) => (forall x y . c x y -> m x y (d x y)) -> t c p q -> m p q (t d p q)
traverseOpposite f  = ixForwards . ttraverse (IxBackwards . f)
```